# Characterisation of coherent sheaves on an algebraic variety

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry

The Wikipedia article on coherent sheaves makes the following claim (without any reference), which I had trouble proving or finding a reference for: on an algebraic variety *X* (or I guess possibly even on a locally noetherian scheme), the coherent sheaves can be defined as the smallest class of sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules with the following two properties:

i)  the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ is itself coherent;

ii) if, in a short exact sequence of sheaves, two of the sheaves are coherent, then so is the third.

I'm skeptical, but I would still like to know if this is true. If so, does anyone know a reference?

Comment: Wouldn't the first Chern class of every sheaf in that class be zero, since $c_1$ is additive over short exact sequences?

Comment: It isn't silly, after all it was claimed at Wikipedia, and you were skeptical..

Comment: I think if you replace (ii) with the requirement that the kernel and cokernel of any morphism between coherent sheaves is coherent, then it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is false. Every sheaf in that class would have zero first Chern class, since $c_1$ is additive over short exact sequences.

Comment: Perhaps the original Wikipedia article meant to have "$\mathcal{O}_{Z}$ is coherent for every subvariety $Z\subseteq X$" in place of (i).  Then the fact that the smallest class of sheaves satisfying (i) and (ii) is the category of coherent sheaves is an application of the usual d&eacute;vissage-type argument.